# My webpage Image displays in Firefox fine, but not in Chrome

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, firefox, web

Here's why I'm confused.  The left flags display fine (in Chrome & Firefox), however the flags on the right are huge and don't appear as the left ones do (in Chrome only).  Even though the code is exactly the same!  Which makes me think the problem has to do with something I'm missing.  I would greatly appreciate any input as I'm still learning.

UPDATE:  Here is a link to view the page:
You can scroll to the right to see the other set of flags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
    <!-- DISCLAIMER ALERT ONE-TIME ONLY -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="firsttime.js"></script>              

    <!-- RED background <body bgcolor="#FF0000"> -->
    <!-- <body bgcolor="#003588"> -->
     <!-- <body bgcolor="#373737"> -->


    <title> Extra Help </title>
        <center>
            <p id="Title">
                <h1>
                    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1914809/Senora/Senora%20bannerfans_6810928%20fancy.jpg"></img>   
                </h1>
            </center>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("Title")
        </script>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#3f3f3f">
<table> 
    <tr> 
    <!-- LEFT FLAGS -->
        <td>  
        <img src="Flag_Spain.jpg" width=90%>        
        <br> 
        <img src="Flag_Spain.jpg" width=90%>        
        <br> 
        <img src="Flag_Spain.jpg" width=90%>        
        <br> 
        <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
        <br> 
        </td>
    <!-- BUTTONS -->
    <td>
        <form action="SenoraLearn.html">
            <input type="submit" value="Learn  ">
            </form>
        <form action="SenoraLearn.html">
            <input type="submit" value="Practice">
            </form>
        <form action="SenoraDiscuss.html">
            <input type="submit" value="Discuss">
            </form>
            <br>
        <form action="SenoraProblem.html">
            <input type="submit" value="Report a Problem">
            </form>
            <br>
        <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>  
    </td> 

    <!-- BEGIN GAP COLUMNS-->   
        <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> 
        <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> 
        <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> 
        <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> 
        <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> 
        <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td>  
        <!-- END GAP COLUMNS -->

    <!-- BEGIN CONTENT COLUMN-->
        <td>
            <!--YOUTUBE VIDEO -->
                <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EkWlmL1Nnfw?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <!-- END YOUTUBE VIDEO -->

            <!-- begin htmlcommentbox.com -->
                <div id="HCB_comment_box"><a href="http://www.htmlcommentbox.com">HTML Comment Box</a> is loading comments...</div> 
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//www.htmlcommentbox.com/static/skins/bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap.css?v=0" />
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" id="hcb"> /*<!--*/ if(!window.hcb_user){hcb_user={};} (function(){var s=document.createElement("script"), l=(""+window.location || hcb_user.PAGE), h="//www.htmlcommentbox.com";s.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");s.setAttribute("src", h+"/jread?page="+escape(l).replace("+","%2B")+"&opts=16862&num=10");if (typeof s!="undefined") document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);})(); /*-->*/ </script>
                <!-- end htmlcommentbox.com -->
                <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> 
            </td> 
        <!-- CONTENT COLUMN --> 
    <!--RIGHT SPACING COLUMN--> 
        <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> 
        <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> 
        <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> 
        <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> 
        <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> 
        <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> 
        <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> 
        <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> 
        <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td> <td> <p> </td>  

    <!-- RIGHT FLAGS -->    
        <td>  
        <img src="Flag_Spain.jpg" width='90%'>
        <br> 
        <img src="Flag_Spain.jpg" width='90%'>
        <br> 
        <img src="Flag_Spain.jpg" width='90%'>
        <br> 
        <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
        <br> 
        </td>

    </tr> 
</table>
<!--END TABLE-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be much better if you could replicate your issue using http://jsfiddle.net so we can see exactly what is going on.  Once you have saved it, provide the URL back here by **editing** your question with it

Comment: Using TABLEs and BRs for formatting - you deserve what you get. It's not 1999.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table formatting is the issue here. Much more browser friendly.

You should be using a setup like

.html

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="column1">
      images here....
   </div>
   <div class="column2">
      content here...
   </div>
   <div class="column3">
      images here......
   </div>
</div>
```

.css

```
.wrapper {
  width: 960px
 }

.column1 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
.column3 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}

.column1 img, .column2 img, .column3 img {
 width: 90%;
}
```

something along those lines